# mod_rewrite to fix bad subdomain naming

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, directory, cdn, subdirectory

I have a lot of uncleverly named folders on my server. They're called things like cdn-1 cdn3 img1 and so on. I have collected all of the files in these folders and put them in one folder, called cdn. Now, I don't want users to get a 404 when they try to access a file that is at cdn-3.website.com/file/img/1.jpg. Instead, is there a way to mod_rewrite this folder so that even if a user tries to access a file at, say, cdn-7382910731293.website.com/file/1.jpeg, it'll still work? This might be far fetched, but I have seen this be done before. The only working code I've found for a solution like this is for a single file, not a folder.

EDIT: This is what I've tried so far. It just won't work. What's the problem with it?

`RewriteRule ^cdn([^/]*).1$ http://cdn.website.com/$1 [L]`

Comment: Look at my edit. That's what I've tried.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest thing would be to use .htaccess to [redirect all 404 pages to a single PHP page](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/), which would in turn check if such a file/image exists in your new cdn folder and either server it or display a valid 404 page.

Don't forget about headers when serving images etc., too ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try make the sub-domains all point to the same place (wherever cdn.website.com points to) and then stick the following in the htaccess on that domain:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(cdn-1|cdn1|img1|etc)\.website\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://cdn.website.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

That should work seamlessly, as long as the files otherwise would be in the same place. That is, only the host name is different and not also the file path after the host name. The RewriteCond is a regular expression I think, so you should be able to write it to match whatever you need.

I have used this method successfully to redirect an old domain to a new one, and to redirect `example.com` to `www.example.com`.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not looking to do a redirect though.

Comment: Um, what are you trying to do then?

Comment: Let's say I want to link users to a file that is located at cdn.website.com/movie.mp4, but I want to give a nicer link - so instead I'd do something like cdn-video.website.com/movie.mp4, or something similar. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So you want to do the opposite? May I ask why? Isn't it better to have a single hostname for your files? I'd find that a lot cleaner anyways... What do you gain from having separate sub-domains for these things if they point to the same place anyways?

Comment: But why is `cdn-video.example.com/movie.mp4` any more helpful or informative than `cdn.example.com/movie.mp4`? The important bits, to me anyways, is the main domain and the file name. And the filename ends in mp4, so it should be fairly obvious that it's a move clip. And if its not, then the person looking at it probably wont think much about the URL anyways :p

Comment: Yes, I suppose that's true, but it's also for flexibility and it'll make reusing old file paths much easier.

Comment: Well I don't get it. Sounds to me like you're making a problem for yourself that you don't really need to have. But do share if you find a good solution to it :p